# SignalR - Can't create url for HubConnection

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, signalr, azure-web-roles

I started to work with SignalR on Visual Studio 2012, so far I got the basic hang of it, I guided myself through [this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/SiteMonitR-dd4fcf77/sourcecode?fileId=65411&pathId=1807543619) example (You can browse the code in the page). I decided I wanted to add a REST service to said example, so I added a basic service to it and it worked.

The next step I wanted to take was to add a communication between the service and SignalR, so according to what the example showed to me, I only needed to create a HubConnection through the url in my project (in this case, the example uses the url http:localhost:4200). You can check the WorkerRoleHubConfiguration class, it has a method that has the next line:

```
return RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("GUI_URL");
```

Where GUI_URL is http:localhost:4200.

In my service class then I just added a method with the following:

```
var url = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("http://localhost:4200");

try
{
    HubConnection _connection = new HubConnection(url);
    IHubProxy _hub = _connection.CreateProxy("SiteMonitR");
    _hub.Invoke("displayResult");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    error = ex.ToString();
}
```

But that throws an exception, [this](http://pastebin.com/XdjsAku3) one.

I don't undertand why I can get the url in the same way the example does, as I'm doing everything as it's done on the Server class.

The goal I'm trying to achieve is that when an endpoint is accesed and something changes in my system, SignalR notifies to the clients connected to it.

I hope anyone can help me understand what's wrong with my work.

**EDIT**

I'm adding my ServiceConfiguration.Local.cscfg, my ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg and ServiceDefinition.csdef files as reference [here](http://pastebin.com/WYUA23qZ), I think the problem should be around there but to be honest I got no idea as to why this isn't working.

**EDIT 2**

I'm getting the following exception at this line `var url = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("http://localhost:4200");`

The exception is:

```
SEHExcetion occurred. External component has thrown an exception.
```

Answer (score 0):

The URL is for a GUI - it has to be a web interface for signalr to negotiate the hub connection.  In the example, the hub (server) sends updates to connections coming from the configured URL - again a web interface (html page).

The logic to communicate needs to reside in the Server class and be called from the worker role.  For example, after making a call to your service in the worker role, then call server.DoSomething("message") to invoke a message to the server.  THat code would look something like:

```
public Class Server 
{ ...
    public void DoSomething(string message)
    {
        _hub.Invoke("doSomething", message);
    }
    ...
}
```

Then in Server.Run() add:

```
    // whenever a DoSomething is called
    _hub.On<string>("doSomething", (message) => _hub.Invoke("doSomething", message));
```

And in SiteMonitRNotificationHub

```
public class SiteMonitRNotificationHub : Hub
{
    ...
    public void DoSomething(string address)
    {
        Clients.doingSomething(address);
    }
    ...
}
```

Finally in the controller script in the web gui:

```
c.siteMonitorHub
...
    .on('doingSomething', function (message) {
        c.doSomething(message);
    })
```

and...

```
this.doSomething= function (message) {
    // do something in your web page with message
};
```

Comment: so why is it not working if I'm using the same url? Do I have to reference it in a different way?

Comment: I changed how I get the url like this `var url = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("GUI_URL");` but I got an exception `External component has thrown an exception.` I'm really lost as to why I can't create the HubConnection object, or am I misinterpreting something?

Comment: RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("name") is an Azure method to get the value from the Azure settings file with the key = "name".  You have the URL, just use var url = "http://localhost:4200".  If you aren't running the website in Azure or the Azure emulator, RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue() will always return an exception, likewise if the setting doesn't exist, you will get an error.

Comment: but I'm running it on the emulator, also I tried to use `var url = "localhost:4200";` but I get the `SEHExcetion occurred. External component has thrown an exception.`

Comment: Does SiteMonitR.Web start and open in a browser?  If so, what is the URL that SiteMonitR.Web runs under when you launch the application? Copy and paste that full URL into the value attribute for setting name="GUI_URL".

Comment: when I run it the url the browser opens is `http://localhost:4200`, but the endpoint of my service I'm trying to make the call to the Hub is `http://localhost:4200/Service1.svc/GetResponse`

Comment: Maybe what I'm trying to do is wrong? The Server class in namespace SiteMonitR has no problem getting the url with `var url = _hubConfiguration.GetHubContainingSiteUrl();`, but my Service1 class in namespace SiteMonitR.Web fails to get the same url by calling the method `RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("GUI_URL");` inside the `GetHubContainingSiteUrl` method. From what you replied it will only work if the call is made inside the WorkerRole? But then how can I use an endpoint in a WebRole to trigger an update to my clients through SignalR?

Comment: The logic I'm trying to do is like this: A device access an endpoint of my Service inside my WebRole, a change in the database will be made, this change must trigger a _hub.On on the Server or it is triggered inside the Service? Then the clients must be updated. In this scenario the device is supposed to send latitude and longitude for a point in a Map through the Service, this location is stored in the database, then both the latitude and longitude must be sent to every client so a pin appears in map that is shown to any client that access the GUI_URL

Comment: follow the logic in the example you started with and that I laid out.  Calls to _hub.On have to be made from the hub (worker role in the example).  The spokes (the web GUI receive the signals from the hub). Hub-Spoke is one to many.  For your logic, replace the worker role with your service - it will have a different endpoint - and include the _hub.On logic where you need it.

Comment: Finally, read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/12/17/signalr-building-real-time-web-applications.aspx - in your case HUB (web service) = SERVER (Server._hub.On) / SPOKE (Web GUI) = CLIENT (browser)

Comment: ok, I made my worker role look like [this](http://pastebin.com/mihZ7GPm) but how do I add the service on the ServiceDefinition.csdef ? I tried [this](http://pastebin.com/DUtK9D09) but Sites is not valid for a WorkerRole, suggestions? and what kind of endpoint will I be accessing?

Comment: so I have to move the logic from the worker role to the web role? I think I'm misinterpreting what you're trying to say to me.

Comment: If you want your hub to be a web service, then yes.

Comment: I meant, does my web service have to inherit from RoleEntryPoint? or do I create a Thread inside my web service?

Comment: read this on how create and deploy a web service in azure - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg651130.aspx - you web service needs to instantiate the signalR Server class - similar to the way the worker role example does - and replace invoke methods with your own.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22159/discussion-between-viperguynaz-and-uriel-arvizu)